# Encode the URL query Param(query value as Some URL) in Angular with Library

Tags: angular

How to encode the URL query params in Angular. For example I am passing one query params as some URL as below.

> http://localhost:8080/homecontroller?siteurl=http://example.com?name=test name&email=test@gmail.com

Due that URL Param(siteurl) URL got broken.
How to encode with some library without manual encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`queryParams`](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlCreationOptions#queryParams)

```ts
let params = {
  siteUrl: 'http://example.com?name=test name&email=test@gmail.com'
};

this.router.navigate(['/homecontroller'], { queryParams: params });
```